# insert id after creating into another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to work out what would be the best way to get the id of item after it is created and pass that id into another table. i.e a user creates a team which is saved into the teams database, I want to allocate that `team_id` into my users table.

I have tried the below without success

```
    def create
    @team = Team.new(params[:team])
    @user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        format.html { redirect_to(teams_url,
                                  :notice => "Team #{@team.name} was successfully created.") }
        format.json { render :json => @team, :status => :created, :location => @team }
        @user.update_attributes(params[:user][@team.id])
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @team.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

team model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :users
  has_many  :events
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :sport
  attr_accessible :name, :division_id, :sport_id
  validates :name, :presence => true

end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  belongs_to :sport
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :availabilities
```

sql executing

```
    Started POST "/teams" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-24 15:24:40 +1100
Processing by TeamsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ztr8E+jg3hCe3cQoDefS3Rw5GQJGZfHsffffbCZiGRs=", "team"=>{"sport_id"=>"19", "division_id"=>"", "name"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Create Team"}
  User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "teams" ("created_at", "division_id", "name", "sport_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 24 Feb 2013 15:24:40 EST +11:00], ["division_id", nil], ["name", "test"], ["sport_id", 19], ["updated_at", Sun, 24 Feb 2013 15:24:40 EST +11:00]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/teams
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options below

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  saved = false

  Team.transaction do
    saved = @team.save
    if saved
      # 1) this should work ?
      @team.users << current_user
      # 2) if that doesn't then this most def
      current_user.team = @team
      current_user.save!
      # 3) or 
      current_user.update_attribute(:team_id, @team.id)
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if saved        
      format.html { redirect_to(teams_url, :notice => "Team #{@team.name} was successfully created.") }
      format.json { render :json => @team, :status => :created, :location => @team }        
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @team.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end     
end
```

Comment: option all 3 options worked, i have opted to use the first one

Comment: In option #2 the save is unnecessary. When both models are persisted then the assignment will update the foreign key.

Comment: in #2 - team has already been saved, i don't believe there will be another call made to the db, unless it is explicit

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to fix the argument your passing to update_attributes

```
@user.update_attributes(:team_id => @team.id)
```

The params hash has no part in it at that point. It contains mostly information from the GET/POST vars, like params[:team] which came from your form.

**UPDATE**

After seeing your models, the update_attributes won't work without making team_id accessible, which is a security issue, generally foreign keys should not be made accessible. Instead replace the update_attributes with an assignment.

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @team.save
      format.html { redirect_to(teams_url, :notice => "Team #{@team.name} was successfully created.") }
      format.json { render :json => @team, :status => :created, :location => @team }
      # use assignment instead to avoid mass assignment errors
      current_user.team = @team
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @team.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: that gives me `undefined method `stringify_keys' for 11:Fixnum`

Comment: Oops, wrote that too quick

Comment: hrmm that build_team doesnt seem to pass the id from the team model to users :S

Comment: Hmm, looked it up in the docs and there's actually not anything about building from the belongs to side of a one-many. Stick with what you have I suppose...

Comment: Cluster reading through the docs your second method should have worked i just cant work out why it didn't

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be solved using active record associations. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
This is the best method for stroing one item id to another item of different databse. So try using active record associations.
Updated

```
    if @team.save
    @user.update_attributes(:team_id => @team.id)
    format.html { redirect_to(teams_url,
                                  :notice => "Team #{@team.name} was successfully created.") }
   format.json { render :json => @team, :status => :created, :location => @team }
```

Use update code after save not after redirect.

Comment: may I see yours associations configuration?

Comment: Add attr_accessible :team_id in your User model

Comment: Then use @user.update_attributes(:team_id => @team.id) in your item crate action it may work.

Comment: i have updated my question to show what is happening when executing